# How to get only element in array - mongodb

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, nosql, nosql-aggregation

Hello sorry i am new in with nosql and mongodb please kindly help me
here is my sample data

```json
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("611532b19c6e77ad0fd50c1c"),
    "status": true,
    "role_name": "DEVELOPER",
    "descr": "DEVELOPER",
    "menu": [
      {
        "permissions": [
          ObjectId("60eeabbc9ca3e3a4f03ff5ee"),
          ObjectId("611125cad17b0c71595298d4"),
          ObjectId("6113e8d69c6e77ad0fd50c08"),
          ObjectId("61279df3f544f6c2db48b92d"),
          ObjectId("612a3f061a1fcead8871e821")
        ],
        "_id": ObjectId("612a46c41a1fcead8871e83f"),
        "menu_id": ObjectId("611fe0b60734048a04812020")
      },
      {
        "permissions": [
          ObjectId("60eeabbc9ca3e3a4f03ff5ee"),
          ObjectId("611125cad17b0c71595298d4"),
          ObjectId("6113e8d69c6e77ad0fd50c08"),
          ObjectId("61279df3f544f6c2db48b92d"),
          ObjectId("612a3f061a1fcead8871e821")
        ],
        "_id": ObjectId("612a46c41a1fcead8871e840"),
        "menu_id": ObjectId("611fee7e0734048a04812022")
      },
      {
        "permissions": [
          ObjectId("60eeabbc9ca3e3a4f03ff5ee"),
          ObjectId("611125cad17b0c71595298d4"),
          ObjectId("6113e8d69c6e77ad0fd50c08"),
          ObjectId("61279df3f544f6c2db48b92d"),
          ObjectId("612a3f061a1fcead8871e821")
        ],
        "_id": ObjectId("612a46c41a1fcead8871e841"),
        "menu_id": ObjectId("6128c64f9bd697e83dbe47b1")
      },
      {
        "permissions": [
          ObjectId("60eeabbc9ca3e3a4f03ff5ee"),
          ObjectId("611125cad17b0c71595298d4"),
          ObjectId("6113e8d69c6e77ad0fd50c08"),
          ObjectId("61279df3f544f6c2db48b92d"),
          ObjectId("612a3f061a1fcead8871e821")
        ],
        "_id": ObjectId("612a46c41a1fcead8871e842"),
        "menu_id": ObjectId("6128c5e19bd697e83dbe47ac")
      }
    ],
    "createdAt": ISODate("2021-08-12T14:39:45.505+0000"),
    "updatedAt": ISODate("2021-08-28T14:23:00.040+0000"),
    "__v": NumberInt(10)
  }
]
```

what is want to get when i input menu_id = ObjectId("611fe0b60734048a04812020")

```
 {
    "permissions" : [
        ObjectId("60eeabbc9ca3e3a4f03ff5ee"), 
        ObjectId("611125cad17b0c71595298d4"), 
        ObjectId("6113e8d69c6e77ad0fd50c08"), 
        ObjectId("61279df3f544f6c2db48b92d"), 
        ObjectId("612a3f061a1fcead8871e821")
    ], 
    "_id" : ObjectId("612a46c41a1fcead8871e83f"), 
    "menu_id" : ObjectId("611fe0b60734048a04812020")
},
```

and this is my query

```
db.getCollection("tbl_roles").find(
 { "menu.menu_id": ObjectId("611fe0b60734048a04812020") }
 )
```

-- to no meaning word just for publish question
In publishing and graphic design, Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used to demonstrate the visual form of a document or a typeface without relying on meaningful content. Lorem ipsum may be used as a placeholder before final copy is available.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) which return only the first element matched in the array.

As explained into docs:

> The $elemMatch operator limits the contents of an  field from the query results to contain only the **first** element matching the $elemMatch condition.

Try this query:

```
db.collection.find({},
{
  "menu": {
    "$elemMatch": {
      "menu_id": ObjectId("611fe0b60734048a04812020")
    }
  }
})
```

Note that you can also add some matches into `find` object [like this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/WKC9axXjCGl)

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/HcQ6S2IDVSc).

Also, if for any reason you need to get more than one result from the array, you can use an `aggregate` query like [this one](https://mongoplayground.net/p/y2k1aJzjFHd)